# Grouping a set of values in dataframe based on the values of a column (or two)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which look like this:

```
  A       B        C          D    E   F   G  H     I      J 
FP002    12     apr-1-2015   113 406 519  85 82  FP001   mar-2016
FP003    7610   may-8-2015   99  552 651  49 64  FP002   oct-2017
FP005    12,    jul-2-2019   102 131 1416 24  89 FP003   may-2021
FP005    1250   jun-1-2018   94  739 833 122 215 FP004   dec-2018
```

I want to have a new dataframe that will look like this (see dates of column C):

```
 A       B        C          D    E   F   G  H     I      J 
FP002    12     apr-2015   113 406 519  85 82  FP001   mar-2016
FP003    7610   may-2015   99  552 651  49 64  FP002   oct-2017
FP005    12,    jul-2019   102 131 1416 24  89 FP003   may-2021
FP005    1250   jun-2018   94  739 833 122 215 FP004   dec-2018
```

And a dataframe like this (see year only of C):

```
  A       B        C    D    E   F   G  H     I      J 
FP002    12     2015   113 406 519  85 82  FP001   mar-2016
FP003    7610   2015   99  552 651  49 64  FP002   oct-2017
FP005    12,    2019   102 131 1416 24  89 FP003   may-2021
FP005    1250   2018   94  739 833 122 215 FP004   dec-2018
```

Question 1: How to arrive with the above dataframes?

Because eventually, I will make a figure that shows the number of cells (in Column A) that belong in the Year 2015, 2016 etc (with respect to Column C)...then another figure for Column J---> total figures 2

and another figure that shows the number of cells (in Column A) that belong in the 1st quarter of the Year 2015, 2016 etc (with respect to Column C)...then another figure for Column J---> total figures 2

NOTE: X axis is the year (and for the next figure is  Quarter number and year)

Question 2: How to plot them by Quarter and by Year?

My code looks like this

```
df.groupby('A')['C'].sum()
```

but this doesnt give me the first dataframe i pointed out.

the figure should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: What's the question? Like, what do you need help with exactly? Check out [ask] for tips.

Comment: After reading [Panda Kim's answer](/a/77342269/4518341), I'm thinking, do you not know how to work with datetimes in Pandas? Check out the User Guide: [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html)

Comment: @wjandrea I edited the question and added Question 1 and 2 above.

Comment: OK, so you don't know how to work with datetimes, eh? Cause this should be really easy with `.resample` once you've parsed them.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['apr-1-2015', 'may-8-2015', 'jul-2-2019', 'jun-1-2018'])
```

s:

```
0    apr-1-2015
1    may-8-2015
2    jul-2-2019
3    jun-1-2018
dtype: object
```

---

**Code**

1.

```
s.str.replace('\d+-', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
0    apr-2015
1    may-2015
2    jul-2019
3    jun-2018
dtype: object
```

2. 

```
s.str.extract(r'(\d+$)')
```

output:

```
    0
0   2015
1   2015
2   2019
3   2018
```

make output to your new dataframe's column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'C':['apr-1-2015', 'may-8-2015', 'jul-2-2019', 'jun-1-2018']})

pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
df['C1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
df['C2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C']).dt.strftime('%b-%Y') 
df['C3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C']).dt.year
df
```

Result:

```
            C        C1          C2     C3
0   apr-1-2015  2015-04-01  Apr-2015    2015
1   may-8-2015  2015-05-08  May-2015    2015
2   jul-2-2019  2019-07-02  Jul-2019    2019
3   jun-1-2018  2018-06-01  Jun-2018    2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strings and don't generate many tables. Just use a `datetime` type for your dates and you will be able to easily resample or group by any unit of time (year, month, but also more complex ones such as quarter, week...)

```
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'], format='%b-%d-%Y')
```

If you really want to change the string:

```
out = df.assign(C=lambda d: d['C'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y'))
```

Output:

```
       A     B         C    D    E     F    G    H      I         J
0  FP002    12  Apr-2015  113  406   519   85   82  FP001  mar-2016
1  FP003  7610  May-2015   99  552   651   49   64  FP002  oct-2017
2  FP005   12,  Jul-2019  102  131  1416   24   89  FP003  may-2021
3  FP005  1250  Jun-2018   94  739   833  122  215  FP004  dec-2018
```

But as you seem to want to aggregate your data for plotting, just convert to datetime and use:

```
df.groupby('A').resample('M', on='C')[['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to duplicate your dataframe ? Prefer create additional columns or change x-axis with matplotlib's [Date formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#date-formatters) and [Date locators](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#date-tick-locators)

```
df['K'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'], format='%b-%d-%Y')
print(df['K'])

# Output
0   2015-04-01
1   2015-05-08
2   2019-07-02
3   2018-06-01
Name: K, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Once the DateTime column is created, use the `dt` accessor to manipulate the [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) attributes (like `year`, `month`, ...) and methods (like `strftime`):

```
>>> df['K'].dt.year
0    2015
1    2015
2    2019
3    2018
Name: K, dtype: int32

>>> df['K'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y').str.lower()
0    apr-2015
1    may-2015
2    jul-2019
3    jun-2018
Name: K, dtype: object
```

For matplotlib, there are plenty of examples on SO to format a date axis.